# Increase stack size of JUnit test in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit4, stack-size

I have a problem that whenever I try to run my JUnit tests, they fail because of a `StackOverflowError`. My problem is that I have a recursive function that traverses through a very large graph to find all possible paths. I have also a recursion counter which counts what the deepest recursion is and with most of the graphs I lie between 3000 to 4000. When I run my JUnit test the `StackOverflowError` always occurs exactly at 2300, no matter what VM arguments I set.

I already tried out `-Xss1m` to `-Xss10m` but to no avail the `StackOverflowError` still occurs at the same recursion depth. I have already searched a bit in the internet and found out that I have also to set the stack size of the running eclipse application. So I did but again to no avail.

Here a few Screenshots where I have already tried to set the stack size:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas what I have missed?

Comment: Whilst this is a valid question, have you considered simply refactoring your code to use a non-recursive approach?

Comment: Yes we currently working on a non-recursive approach to solve this problem, but for the time being we need this solution because it's more complicated as we thought at the first instance ...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late to answer to answer this question now ...

Solution first:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- look here -->
                <argLine>-Xss18m</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Check the line of `<!--look here >`, I don't know how to highlight it in the code block.

The reason why your solution is not working:
The JVM you are modifying is not used by junit.

If you write a main function in this class, and it will use it.